# What happens after SDL_GetTicks() has reached sizeof(Uint32)?

Tags: time, sdl, unsigned

The return type of SDL's time function `SDL_GetTicks()` is `Uint32` which is a `typedef uint32_t Uint32`. The function gives the milliseconds after the start of the SDL application.

Now, 32 bits of unsigned integer holding milliseconds are roughly 50 days. Assuming I write an application (e.g. a game server that runs 24/7) that uses this function to calculate run speed, what will happen after 50 days of runtime when the 32 bit unsigned integer is full?

Comment: The question does not show significant effort to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It overflows.

According to [this website](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlgetticks.html) and some other resources, the value will start over every 49.7 days.

Comment: and that is because :